# Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic

Running Synaptic I get the following error message:

```
E: The package hl1440lpr needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
```

Upon accepting the message, Synaptic quits.

Comment: What set of instructions / web site were you following and what problem were you having ?

Comment: Related: [Fix half-installed package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490671/fix-half-installed-package), [How to fix “Package is in a very bad inconsistent state” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

Answer (score 118):

Well we may need a few steps to fix this.

1. Start with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-all hl1440lpr
   ```
2. If that fails:

   ```
   sudo rm -i /var/lib/dpkg/info/hl1440lpr.*
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq hl1440lpr
   ```
3. Confirm Apt is fixed. The following command should return no errors:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Comment: I ran into this situation when I was upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10 but accidently suspended the computer midway. Upon waking the computer, the upgrade had (obviously) failed and a red icon appeared next to the battery meter which said that `E:The package xterm needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.` Once I applied the suggestion here, `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all xterm` everything was fixed. Thanks! ps, it would be nice if you could edit `sodo` to say `sudo`, I wouldn't nitpick but that would derail someone who didn't know anything about linux.

Comment: Thank you bodhi.zazen. Your solution worked for my faulty brother-driver; dcpj4110dwlpr.

Comment: Perfect! First solution failed and hanged the process, but second one worked. Thanks! (tried on debian server)

Comment: Just an addon to @panther The sudo dpkg --remove --force-all hl1440lpr
did work for other packages, mine was a libperl5.22 that seems to have crash during an update. The only issue was that it required me to be in root permission. As I was in google cloud, su did not work until I made a password.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out, this wouldn't repair using the regular commands because I had disabled the `multiverse` repository in the software and updates window, *after installing the package*.

I read to do this in a post somewhere else, and it wasn't until another post I read that had me double check to make sure it was **ENABLED**, then I realized I never should have disabled that in the first place.

Enabling the multiverse repository again enabled me to reinstall the package.

---

So, generally if this sorts of errors happen, make sure you haven't disabled the software source from which this package comes.

Answer (score 4):

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq   broken---stuff
```

(plus file erasing)

works like a charm. synaptic should offer this function instead of dying and leaving people with a huge mess. synaptic is not user friendly.

Comment: you have to be careful with this command, depending on what you are removing, it could cascade into removing your entire desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Just open `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file as root and remove the corresponding entry from it.

Comment: Extremely important. This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The package error can be because of abruptly closing the ongoing upgrade of packages. For this , you can use this linux command.

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this step:

```
sudo rm -i /var/lib/dpkg/info/package.*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package
```

and after that residual config was reamining after using

```
sudo dpkg --purge package_name
```

everything got fixed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 0):

run the following commond on the terminal

1)sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status status.bkp

2)sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status

3)then Search for the package name that appears in the error.
Note that, in our case the culprit package was ‘flectra’ which was in
‘purge reinstreq half-installed’ state. After you have located the
culprit package, delete the section of information related to that
package and save the file.
In our case, we deleted the section related to ‘flectra’
inside the rectangle and saved the file.
Close ‘gedit’ when done.

then try to install the pakage you want to install and you fill find no
error now :)