# Fix half-installed package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am getting error while using `sudo apt-get upgrade` stating:

```
dpkg: error processing libgfortran3:amd64 (--configure):
  package libgfortran3:amd64 is not ready for configuration
  cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
  libgfortran3:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It does not seem to block the installation/upgrade other applications.
I believe this problem arose due to direct shutting down of my PC while the application was being upgraded.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: [How to fix “Package is in a very bad inconsistent state” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error), [Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it)

Comment: I found this command useful to list packages that are not correctly installed: `dpkg -l | grep -e '^i[^i]'`. Each package appears on a line, and the first two characters of the line are the (1) desired state and (2) status. Desired of `i` means "Install", and status of `i` would mean "Installed". So the regex is "all lines that start with `i` but don't have `i` in the second position". So an unpacked but not configured package could be `iU`, and a package that was configured but didn't complete could be `iF` (halF configured).

To get the full list of status: `dpkg -l | head -n 2`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run libgfortran3:amd64
```

That's just a dry-run. I'm not sure what removing `libgfortran3` will take with it but run that and see. Assuming it's not going to gobble the whole system, run it again without the `--dry-run` and then you can `sudo apt-get install ...` the packages you need back.

Comment: Worked out, thanks! For the record, I ran it and it said `dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting a removal` so I downloaded the package manually from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and ran `sudo dpkg -i WHERE/THE/DOWNLOADED/PACKAGE/IS`. Then it became all good.

Comment: In my case, after following these instructions, just running 'apt-get install -f' reinstalled the package and also fixed several others with broken dependencies because of it.  This was for the libx11-data package on debian 7.

Comment: Without `--dry-run`, as you said, it worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 84):

For the half installed package error, --reinstall worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename
```

Comment: Yes, but a warning that after reinstalling packagename, apt-get will then proceed to configure any half-configured packages.

Comment: this is safer than the accepted answer imho.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstal  ncurses-base and later I ran the sudo apt-get update using the root user (sudo -s), it worked just like that...

Comment: great. only that solution solved my problem

Comment: this did it for me. php-pear was giving me an headache. thanks!

Comment: This worked for me for:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv

Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I was able to find which packages were half-installed by looking in /var/log/dpkg.log

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall packagename
```

This works like charm. It resolved an issue that I had been experiencing for months. My case was with the package `libmysqlcppconn7v5`

All I did was run `sudo apt install --reinstall libmysqlcppconn7v5`

Answer (score 6):

I got a same "half-installed package" problem with a package kibana. I got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing kibana (--configure):
package kibana is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
  kibana
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If anyone is still facing this kind of problem, then you can try this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/kibana*
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo rm kibana*
apt-get --reinstall install kibana
```

This works for me. You just need to replace the word 'kibana' with your half-installed package name.

Comment: This just removes the pkg from dpkg. It doesnt remove any artifacts that were actually unpacked and moved to `/usr/bin` or wherever. You could end up w/1.5 actual installs, depending on where it originally broke. Although, from there checking the source pkg/debian directory, there should be a makefile or similar, which would give the locations of any stragglers.

Comment: If this answer doesn't work you may also need to run `rm /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/packagename`. Replace the word 'packagename' with your half-installed package.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fix this through GUI, you can use synaptic. Synaptic is an excellent package management tool that used to be included in older versions of ubuntu.
To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

click on fix broken packages.

Comment: synaptic does not list the package in broken category :(

Comment: @Barun [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081938/) contains a screenshot showing how to show and fix broken packages in Synaptic.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix your problem without re-installing the package.

```
sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove <package_name here>
```

Followed by: `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Why `--force-remove-reinstreq`? The package manager doesn't state that a re-installation is required. Generally, a regular removal works just fine for unconfigured packages. -1

Comment: It's just what I do when `sudo apt-get remove <package` is out of option and I don't want to re-install that half-installed package .Then,  I use `--force-remove-reinstreq` to remove those junks..

PS : It's on Linux Mint.. I doubt if it'll be any different as Linux is  based on Ubuntu..

Comment: The package manager works the same in all Debian-based distributions (that's what `dpkg` stands for after all), but you shouldn't use `--force-*` "just in case". The error messages are there for a reason and shouldn't be taken lightly by inexperienced users, which is why you shouldn't suggest unnecessary `--force-*` options to them. Otherwise we could just recommend to always use `--force-all` or, better yet, remove the `--force-*` options from `dpkg` altogether and have them be the default behaviour because that would be easier and more convenient.

Comment: Okay, Admit it... I was being more concerned about getting the job done than, knowing what and how exactly it is done..  Apologies..

Comment: Hm… I'm just seeing that the accepted answer suggests the same. So I might be wrong about `--force-remove-reinstreq` being unnecessary. But that also means that your answer is (almost) a duplicate of it. Better luck next time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster haha... You guys treat re("Stack[.]*") like it's some kind of game.. :D

Comment: If you mean that both games and SE have rules of engagement, then I agree with you.

Comment: @DavidFoester The `--force-remove-reinstreq` flag doesn't try to reinstall. The reinstallrequest is a flag tacked onto half configured packages, which is why they wont uninstall in the first place.