# Got stuck while updating to linux kernel 4.10.0-38

Tags: apt, nvidia, kernel, virtualbox, update-manager

My software updater got stuck while installing the linux kernel 4.10.0-38. When I killed the process and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I got:

```
Setting up linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic (4.10.0-38.42) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
```

And then nothing happened for a very long time. When I press `control + C`, I got:

```
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic.postinst line 110.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic (4.10.0-38.42) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-38-generic
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-38-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-38-generic
```

And it got stuck again. Then I press `control + C` again, I got:

```
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic
 linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic
 linux-headers-generic
```

Then I run `sudo dpkg --config -a` and got:

```
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 linux-headers-generic Generic Linux kernel headers

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic Linux kernel headers for version 4.10.0 on 64 
 linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit
```

Now I can't install anything using apt, because whenever I use apt, it will try to configure the kernel and get stuck again. I also need to manually select kernel every time I boot my computer because the default 4.10.0-38 kernel didn't work. How can I fix that?

I tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/850131) by replacing all `4.4.0-38` in commands with `4.10.0-38`, but it didn't work.

Now my `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is:

```
Package: linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Installed-Size: 151751
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux
Version: 4.10.0-38.42
Depends: linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic, crda | wireless-crda
```

P.S. I'm using nvidia driver and have VirtualBox installed. However, I don't have the `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd` file.

Answer (score 0):

similar with me - got stuck while updating to linux kernel 4.10.0-38. When nothing happened for a long time I restarted the computer. But not even the restart was successfull, I could only restart in advanced mode, selecting the Ubuntu, with linux 4.8.0-36-generic option, (non of the linux 4.8.10 option led to a successfull restart.)

For me this helped:  askubuntu.com/questions/253244/reinstall-latest-kernel
 based on this I tried this: 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-4.8.0-36-generic 
It took time (0,5-1 hour) to install, but reboot was successfull afterwards.