# Unable to install Python in Ubuntu 20.04 - dpkg: errror

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, 20.04, python, dpkg

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in my Oracle VM.

I am trying to install python in it.

When I tried entering `sudo apt install python2` command, the system throws me an error:

```
vinod@vinod-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install python2
[sudo] password for vinod:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python2 is already the newest version (2.7.17-2ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic (5.4.0-42.46) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic (5.4.0-42.46) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd:
run-parts: failed to exec /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd: Exec format error
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
vinod@vinod-VirtualBox:~$
```

Is there any possibility the Ubuntu installation is crashed in my VM?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu as a VM under Virtualbox?  If so, it looks like your VBox extensions may have gotten corrupted (those the error about vboxadd). Try reinstalling your extensions... did you install them from the ISO?

Comment: @BrianTurek Yes. I have installed it using the ISO image which is downloaded from Ubuntu website. Could you please tell me how do I install the extensions.

Comment: You seem to be misreading the apt output. You DID successfully install python2 (`python2 is already the newest version (2.7.17-2ubuntu4)`).

Comment: The vboxadd exec error looks very similar to [Ubuntu 16.04 broken kernel packages won't let me install or remove anything with apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850101/ubuntu-16-04-broken-kernel-packages-wont-let-me-install-or-remove-anything-with)