# How to fix configuration issues of an old kernel in order to make upgrade possible in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, upgrade, kernel, configuration

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 on a VM VirtualBox. But when running the following code:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am receiving the following error message:

```
 (Reading database ... 248247 files and directories currently
 installed.) Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
 (4.4.0-109.132) ... run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic update-initramfs: Generating
 /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: executing
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.4.0-109-generic
 /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic run-parts: failed to exec
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd: Exec format error run-parts:
 /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd exited with return code 1 dpkg: error
 processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic (--remove): 
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
 Errors were encountered while processing: 
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
 returned an error code (1)
```

I do not know how to fix the configuration files of 109 files. But here is the output of `uname -r`:

```
4.4.0-116-generic
```

And here is a full list of available versions when running `dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+' | grep -Fv $(uname -r)`

```
 ri  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic               4.4.0-109.132         
 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

 ii  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic               4.4.0-112.135         
 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I cannot seem to find a solution in this website as it seems I am making the problem more severe by incorrect application of the solutions. Your help in fixing my machine is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post ([Apt fails to remove partially installed kernel and can't install any other packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650732/apt-fails-to-remove-partially-installed-kernel-and-cant-install-any-other-packa/652077#652077)),

1. I created a back up of the status file in case something goes wrong:

   `sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.backup`
2. I opened `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with `gedit` and searched and deleted ONLY the references of the broken packages. Here is the code to verify such packages: (the status will tell you if they area really broken):

   `dpkg --status linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic`

   `dpkg --status linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic`
3. I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure that issues are fixed.