# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) after sudo apt-get install --fix-missing

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, thunderbird

Ubuntu version 16.04

This is what I get when running

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
```

Even when I want to download freecad from terminal also got the same error.

code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 316 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfreetype6 amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.3 [316 kB]
Fetched 316 kB in 2s (110 kB/s)        
dpkg: error processing package libfreetype6:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grub-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-common is No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                 not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64:
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaviNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                           ng unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of firefox:
 firefox depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package firefox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.15.90); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of imagemagick-6.q16:
 imagemagick-6.q16 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 imagemagick-6.q16 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package imagemagick-6.q16 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of imagemagick:
 imagemagick depends on imagemagick-6.q16 (= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.7); however:
  Package imagemagick-6.q16 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package imagemagick (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgd3:amd64:
 libgd3:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libgd3:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64:
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.9.9); however:
  Package libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 depends on libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2); however:
  Package libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:amd64:
 libqt4-opengl:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libqt4-opengl:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl-dev:
 libqt4-opengl-dev depends on libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2); however:
  Package libqt4-opengl:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libqt4-opengl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64:
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 depends on libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (= 2.16.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pil:amd64:
 python3-pil:amd64 depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package python3-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird:
 thunderbird depends on libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1); however:
  Package libfreetype6:amd64 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird-gnome-support:
 thunderbird-gnome-support depends on thunderbird (= 1:52.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package thunderbird is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird-gnome-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird-locale-en:
 thunderbird-locale-en depends on thunderbird (>= 1:52.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package thunderbird is not configured yet.
 thunderbird-locale-en depends on thunderbird (<< 1:52.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~); however:
  Package thunderbird is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird-locale-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird-locale-en-gb:
 thunderbird-locale-en-gb depends on thunderbird-locale-en; however:
  Package thunderbird-locale-en is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird-locale-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird-locale-en-us:
 thunderbird-locale-en-us depends on thunderbird-locale-en; however:
  Package thunderbird-locale-en is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird-locale-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of thunderbird-locale-id:
 thunderbird-locale-id depends on thunderbird (>= 1:52.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package thunderbird is not configured yet.
 thunderbird-locale-id depends on thunderbird (<< 1:52.1.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.1~); however:
  Package thunderbird is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package thunderbird-locale-id (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfreetype6:amd64
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64
 libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64
 firefox
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64
 imagemagick-6.q16
 imagemagick
 libgd3:amd64
 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64
 libqt4-opengl:amd64
 libqt4-opengl-dev
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64
 python3-pil:amd64
 thunderbird
 thunderbird-gnome-support
 thunderbird-locale-en
 thunderbird-locale-en-gb
 thunderbird-locale-en-us
 thunderbird-locale-id
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

my source list:

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: Post all of your sources list. Also it is a good idea to always be on latest Ubuntu release.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Danial Behzadi, I have already upload my sources list. what should I do now ?

Comment: Didn't you add any additional source/repository?

Comment: yess, yesterday I  installed Spotify.. I just copy and paste code to terminal. Then today I would like to install Freecad , get this error (1) , and when uninstall it also get the same error, even also got the same error for sudo apt-get install --fix -missing and others.

Comment: Can you provide the code you pasted to terminal?

Comment: @Danial Behzadi , #1 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886

Comment: #2 echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

Comment: #3 sudo apt-get update

Comment: #4 sudo apt-get install spotify-client

Comment: This is the link : [https://www.spotify.com/id/download/linux/]

Comment: Can you put outputs of `apt update` and `sudo apt install --reinstall libfreetype6`?

Comment: apt update : No Error ............Hit:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:4 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Fetched 306 kB in 15s (19,3 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: 'sudo apt install --reinstall libfreetype6' no error , I can't copy and paste the output because there is too long cannot copy to comment

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` & `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` no more error! IT WORKS!!!  @Danial Behzadi... Thank You very much for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this issue. Try running these commands one by one

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

These steps helped me for fixing this issue.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Use the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/490677/557359