# Unable to uninstall anything or due to Python 2.7 error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python-2.7

I am not able to uninstall any program on Ubuntu due to a Python config error.
Some googling led me to do a download and install missing Python packages and then execute:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But still I see the same error. Posting below.

```
>> **sudo apt-get -f install**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/224 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package python2.7 (--configure):
 package python2.7 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python2.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/490671/250300 might help. However, be careful with Python 2 since APT itself relies on it AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove package completely using following command in terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python2.7
```