# dpkg error with install-info

Tags: dpkg

I have an issue with dpkg and install-info. I cannot add any new packages without encountering a couple errors:

```
   Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: source: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Clearly there is an issue with /etc/environment.

I have tried solutions from:

- [Upgrade Problems - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1672653)
- [Fix half-installed package - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490671/)
- [How To Solve “sub process usr bin dpkg returned an error code 1″ Error in Ubuntu - It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/)

I have also reinstalled and purged/reinstalled install-info.  I have checked the paths for /etc/environments and they conform to the first url above.

Any help appreciated & Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

After some further digging. The java on this system is messed up after having issues with Ubiquiti's controller after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. Removing java references from /etc/environment did the trick.

What my etc/environment looked like before:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" source /etc/environment
```

Fixed Version:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Reference: [Upgrade Problems - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1672653)