# Can't use apt install at all after installing a deb package "intellij-idea-ultimate needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it"

Tags: apt, package-management, intellij

`apt install` does not work, for example:

```
$ apt install uget 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package intellij-idea-ultimate needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

This problem arose after I installed `intellij idea` using [this `.deb` file from Launchpad](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/i/intellij-idea-ultimate/intellij-idea-ultimate_2017.2.3-1_all.deb).

Comment: Did you get an error during the installation of IntelliJ idea ? Did you use a (1) `.deb` file, (2) a `.zip` or `tar.gz` archive,  or (3) a repository to install the software ?

Comment: solve with :`
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intellij-idea-community
`

Comment: This is related to [Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it) and I had voted to close it as a duplicate of that. But since the actual goal here seems to have been to install a particular program, I'm no longer sure we should close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `apt` is trying to reinstall or update the `intellij-idea-ultimate` but the system does not find the corresponding `.deb` file.

As I know, IntelliJ Idea does not have an official repository you can use with `apt` or `apt-get` to install and update their dependencies. You usually use the official `.tar.gz` file or an [unofficial repository to install IntelliJ](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/08/intellij-idea-2017-2-3-available-for-download-ubuntu-ppa/).

If you are using the unofficial repository, you may...

- Try `aptitude` to solve any inconsistency.
- Download the `.deb` files from the [unofficial ppa repository](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu/pool/main/i/).

If you want to enable that PPA and install from it, you can run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intellij-idea-community
```