# I can not install anything using sudo apt-get install

Tags: 16.04, apt

I can not install anything using sudo apt-get install

For example when I try to install libnlopt-dev, it gives the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev
[sudo] password for burcak: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

When I try to dist-upgrade, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

And also  `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives the following error:

```
    $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-gpgme (0.3-1.1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-gpgme (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
     apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
      Package apport is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up python-gobject-2 (2.28.6-12ubuntu1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-gobject-2 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-cairo (1.8.8-2) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-cairo (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-lockfile (1:0.12.2-1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-lockfile (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up python-pil:amd64 (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
        from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
      File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of asymptote:
     asymptote depends on python-pil; however:
      Package python-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package asymptote (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-dropbox:
     nautilus-dropbox depends on python-gpgme; however:
      Package python-gpgme is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package nautilus-dropbox (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gtk2:
     python-gtk2 depends on python-cairo (>= 1.0.2-1.1); however:
      Package python-cairo is not configured yet.
     python-gtk2 depends on python-gobject-2 (>= 2.21.3); however:
      Package python-gobject-2 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package python-gtk2 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pil.imagetk:amd64:
     python-pil.imagetk:amd64 depends on python-pil (= 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1); however:
      Package python-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package python-pil.imagetk:amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     python-gpgme
     apport-gtk
     python-gobject-2
     python-cairo
     python-lockfile
     python-pil:amd64
     asymptote
     nautilus-dropbox
     python-gtk2
     python-pil.imagetk:amd64
```

Any help?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Does `apt update` help with anything?

Comment: My ubuntu version:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: It seems that $ sudo apt-get update works but does  not help me to install.
Hit:1 http://mirror.hmc.edu/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.hmc.edu/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                    
Hit:3 http://mirror.hmc.edu/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://mirror.hmc.edu/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install -f` (idem `--fix-broken`)? _Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place_, `man apt-get` for more info.

Comment: It also asks for apport package  `$sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: What do `type python` and `python --version` say?

Comment: My python version is Python 3.5.2. But I have also python 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

From these error messages:

```
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
Package apport is not configured yet.
```

It would seem there is an issue with apport.
Kindly change your download servers then try reinstalling apport.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apport
```

#### Edit 1

To change the download server, kindly search in dash for 'Software & Updates' and open it. On the first tab, in the section 'Download from' kindly select the main server if another is selected.
See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: How to change the download server?  `$ sudo apt install --reinstall apport

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: Hi @burcak I have added in the instructions

Comment: I  changed the download server to Main Server. It gave the same error in dialog box.     **Failed to load the package list
This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers
E:The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

Comment: @burcak Kindly check out this answer and see if it helps: https://askubuntu.com/a/88375/163331

Comment: `$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-all apport`  did not work

Comment: It gave `dpkg: apport: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41).` and it goes on

Comment: I tried `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq apport`
and I got `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of apport:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41).

dpkg: error processing package apport (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport`

Comment: I followed these steps: `sudo -i`
`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info`
`rm -rf apport*`

`dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq`