# The package "software-properties-gtk" needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, software-center, python3, python-2.7, django

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.
Whenever I tried to install new package,

"The package software-properties-gtk needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

this error is occurred:

[image]

Thanks.

**Edit**

`apt-cache policy software-properties-gtk`

`Installed : 0.96.20 Candidate: 0.96.20`

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024367/edit) your question above and indicate which version of Ubuntu are you using. Please do not put images of texts in the question. Always copy and paste codes you used, outputs and errors in the question and then format them with the { } button above the edit window.

Comment: What's the output of "apt-cache policy software-properties-gtk"?

Comment: @Logix, It shows:-- Installed : 0.96.20  Candidate: 0.96.20

Comment: So it doesn't look like there are issues with your repositories. Try: "sudo apt update" and then "sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk".

Comment: @Logix, Same error is generated. Now what should i do?

Comment: See if you have any repositories disabled by going to "Software & Updates" (called Software Sources in older Ubuntu versions I believe). If that fails, see the answers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it It's a different package but the same situation (so change the commands for your problem).

Comment: When i tried to open "Software & updates", it doesn't open. And when i tried the solution which is given in this link,  still same error is occurred. And one more thing that, there is one red circle with minus symbol inside it. what does that mean?    And  Thanks for your support.

Comment: @JaySojitra This is very tricky to debug. Do any errors show up when you try to run "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk" in a terminal?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. You said run "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk" in terminal. How to run this file?

Comment: By running this file, it shows error that "no such file or derectory". And Yes, I also can't fine "etc" file in "/usr/bin" file list. Is there any chances that because of missing this file  error is occurred ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all software-properties-gtk`
That's happened cause the software-properties-gtk was not installed correctly and you probably deleted it's archive.

Comment: I do *not* recommend removing `software-properties-gtk`, it will also remove `ubuntu-desktop`.