# sudo apt-get install not working to install plank and another applications

Tags: 16.04, apt

here i want to install plank (ppa:docky-core/stable), but when i tried

`sudo apt-get install plank`

it's didn't working also i tried install another application still didn't working and there's show me this message.
Also i was tried this command
`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` but still didn't working too

here is the message:
[image]

and here is output of **sources.list** :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
```

anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Please, edit your question to post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. And BTW, you forgot to type the name of your installation package.

Comment: okay sir, i have been edit my question check it now

Comment: Your `sources.list` seems OK. There is no package name in your screenshot. Please, can you post the real output of `sudo apt install plank`?

Comment: @Olimjon here it is https://i.postimg.cc/tJ4D410X/image.png and my packages https://i.postimg.cc/fb7v77Dz/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I understood. You have malfunctioned Visual Studio Code (Terminal name is `code`) that is making other packages not installable. 
So do these steps:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all code
```

If that fails:

```
sudo rm -i /var/lib/dpkg/info/code.*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq code
```

Confirm Apt is fixed. The following command should return no errors:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Credits goes to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it).