# Ubuntu 18.04 add package management

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, package-management, 20.04

I am facing the issue past from four days please any help from community. When I run command to download or upgrade am getting below error.

````
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package atlas-metadata-3-1-0-0-78-storm-plugin needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.```
````

Comment: Hello, first of all its better to put your code in the code segment. Also, you can look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it)
I have done it myself.

Comment: You need to figure out where you originally got that package from. Are you using something non-Ubuntu add-on application named Atlas? If you are not using it anymore, it can be deleted...but that's a last resort, as there is tedious cleanup needed afterward.

Comment: Aaryan Bhagat issue solved thank you