# E: The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: kernel

When I go to upgrade the system with `apt-get upgrade` the message appears:
**E: The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

I am a new user in Ubuntu, I need a step by step on how to solve it, please.

Comment: Please give us the command that you used and provide the entire unredacted output.  So that we are able to accurately parse the information, add three backticks on the lines before and after anything that goes into or comes out of your terminal.  Did you use the command `sudo apt update` before running the `upgrade` command?

Comment: yes, @Nmath, first I use apt update, and when I update, the following happens: `@midas-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it).  I would follow the top answer on this question.  Notice that you will need to substitute your problematic package's name in these commands.  Keep a log of your input and output in case you need additional help. Please use the **edit** link under your question to add details. It can be hard to read terminal output without monospace formatting *and* line breaks.

Comment: Nmath, I was able to solve it using the instructions from the link you sent. Thank you very much!