# Installing cuda tool kit and ubuntu crashed cause a new issue where i cant install anything

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

Here is what happend when i run anything with `apt` or `apt-get`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package cuda-repo-debian11-12-1-local needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Tried removing all the PPAs that were not necessary. Tried reinstalling using [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). But still, the issue stays.

Comment: Didn't you get that deb directly from Nvidia, and used dpkg to install it?  Try that again, but look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010
You might want to use the .run script instead. Reject the Nvidia driver offer, and override the system location for lib/bin installs to the local cuda lib/bin locations.

Comment: I did the issue was that my ubuntu hard crashed during installation and it got stuck even after I tried to reinstall. But https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it fixed it now I will try to reinstall tool kit

Answer (score -1):

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it) I was able to able at least stop the `E: The package cuda-repo-debian11-12-1-local needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`